# Data Combining- Need to combine monthly Atttendance entered in different sheet into one

Tags: excel, vba

I have monthly attendance on different sheets (almost 4 years).
The employee names might be in a different order or new employees might join. But the employee reg Number is unique.
Future employees will be added as new rows at the end.
Required:

1. Wanted to combine them all in one sheet and start entering the attendance in the combined sheet from now onwards.
2. In the Combined Sheet, I want a combo box (Or something else) to select a particular month and if I select that particular month it should hide (or filter not sure whether it is possible to filter horizontally) all the other days.
3. Need a button or something else to create days for the coming months.
4. Need to change the formula in Combined Sheet D to G Columns to get the subtotal values.

Please note that values in the COmbined sheet now doest not meet my requirements now.

Thanks in Advance and sorry for too many requests.

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question. Instead, include the part of the code in question (in text format), and possibly some screenshots if you need them.

Comment: If the employee reg number is unique then use index() with match().